# Exclude dev packages from Anaconda when deploying

Tags: python, anaconda, pipenv

I use Anaconda to obtain Python 3.7 even on machines running Debian stable. I have a separate Conda environment for every project I develop.

Naturally, I also install all the packages I need for running and for developing the projects in the same Anaconda environment. This could be Pandas and scikit-learn, but also flake8 and ipdb3.

The list of development requirements (and all requirements implied by them) bloats the Anaconda environment considerably. I would like to to exclude them from any deployment automatically and only install semantically required projects. For `pip` there now exists a solution called `pipenv` which adds support for this use case.

Now I could use `pipenv` inside `conda`, but then I would have to orchestrate two tools. Also, this would not solve the problem for packages available only in Anaconda.

Exists some way for `conda` to support a separation in deployment and dev environments? Some way to automatically track what must be deployed and what should be excluded from deployments?

Comment: Sure, you can use separate `environment.yml` files, but they will have to be manually curated.

Comment: If you make it an answer, I could accept it.